# Decimal value issue

Tags: java, numbers, double

I've got a really annoying task to do, and stuck with it.
So: I need to write a function which gives back the value of a floating number after the decimal.
For example: the param would be:5.456-> and the returning value should be:456.

I can not use String (of course this would be easy this way).

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires some steps to do it with primitives like `float` or `double`. If you were allowed to use `BigDecimal`, this would just be one line of code.

Given `double d = 5.456`;

- first, cut off the part before the floating point.

  - do this by `int full = (int)d;` which will be 5
  - the subtract full from it: `d-full` will now be only the part after the point, so `.456`
- now use a loop to multiply the value by 10 until the "after the point" part is 0.

The special thing here is that when you use double, you have floating point precision issues. That means that `d` will have the value `0.4560000000000004` in between. To solve that, let's introduce an epsilon.

The full code looks like this:

```
private static final double EPS = 1e-5;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 5.456;
    System.out.println(afterDot(d));
}

private static int afterDot(double d) {
    d = getDecimals(d);
    while(getDecimals(d) > EPS){ //decimals will likely never be 0 because of precision, so compare with a really small EPS instead of 0
        d *= 10;
    }
    //cast the result to an int to cut off the double precision issues
    return (int)d;
}

private static double getDecimals(double d) {
    int full = (int) d;
    d = d-full;
    return d;
}
```

This prints `456`. I am very sure this can be optimized somehow, but it's a working first draft.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the remainder, multiplied by 10 until the remainder is 0. Using `BigDecimal` to prevent rounding issues that looks like this:

```
final BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal("5.456");
BigDecimal x = input.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
while (x.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
    x = x.multiply(new BigDecimal(10));
}
System.out.println(x.longValue());
```

Comment: @user16320675 because some people just focus on the problem in front of them rather than trying to solve similar problems (different inputs) through an abstracted solution.

Comment: I don't think `BigDecimal` is "allowed" here at all since it just provides all the necessary methods. Which completely defeats the purpose of the task, which I assume is some homework assignment

Comment: Yes, you are right, `unscaledValue` would be shorter. 
First line is just the input, I would assume that it is okay to use String there. If we use `new BigDecimal(5.456)` instead, we get rounding issues and `unscaledValue` would output `45600000000000040500935938325710594654083251953125`...

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways that don't adjust for floating point anomalies.

```
double s = 5.456;
System.out.println(s%1);
```

or

```
System.out.println(s-(int)s);
```

both print

```
0.4560000000000004
```

Or use `BigDecimal` and adjust the scale and subtract the integer value.

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(s)
      .setScale(3)
      .subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf((int)s)));
```

prints

```
.456
```